# Javascript Fetch api [object object]

Tags: javascript

Why is the code I try to run below return as [object object]?

```
var request = new Request('data/some.json');

  fetch(request).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(json) {
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = json.items;
  });
```

Comment: Use `response.data`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = json.items;` is the issue here.

You should do:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json.items);
```

This is because if you try to paint a plain JavaScript object in the DOM, it'll call the object's `toString` function, which will result in `[object object]`.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely because your response is a JSON string representing an object, which is then parsed to a JavaScript object.

When you try to use this object as `innerHTML`, it is stringified via `toString()`, which in turn returns `[object Object]`:

```js
console.log(({foo: "bar"}).toString()); // "[object Object]"
```

---

If you want to display the JSON representation of the object, simply skip the step where you parse your JSON into a JavaScript object via `json()` and use the plain text representation obtained via `text()` instead:

```
var request = new Request('data/some.json');

fetch(request).then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
}).then(function(text) {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = text;
});
```

Comment: If you only use `text`, `json.items` will likely be `undefined`.