# Only displays [object object], and not working with subpath to display data from API endpoint

Tags: javascript, html, object, fetch-api

I am using an API to draw data
var city = window.location.pathname;
var url = '//apiurl';

```
var infoCity = document.getElementById("info")

fetch(url).then(response => {
    return response.json();
}).then(data => {
    data.innerHTML += data;
    console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("there is an error")
});
```

This gets me the data, but it does not display the data in my html file, where I have a div with the id "info".

Instead, it just says `[Object Object]`, which is my first problem.

Second, if a user types mysite.com/key, I want to display the data based on that key

I have an HTTP-server setup, but it is not working when I type localhost.com/8080/key.

However, hardcoding the response such as

```
var url = '//apiurl/specifickey' gets the data.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Fetch api \[object object\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40727504/javascript-fetch-api-object-object)

Answer (score 0):

The context of info variable needs to be changed.

```
var city = window.location.pathname;
console.log(city);

var url = '//restcountries.eu/rest/v2/capital' + city;
const info = document.querySelector("#info");

fetch(url).then(response => {
    return response.json();
}).then(data => {
    info.innerHTML = data;
    console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("there is an error")
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, altough it did not work. It seems to give me a response if I comment out the line "info.innerHTML = data".

Comment: It seems you don't  have any dom element with id `info`

Comment: I have a <div id="info"></div> in my index.html file. Should be enough no?

Comment: Share the console error if you are encountered with.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for first problem is

```
var key = window.location.pathname;
var url = 'apiurl';

var infoCity = document.getElementById("info")

fetch(url).then(response => {
    return response.json();
}).then(data => {
    data.innerHTML += data[0].key;
    console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("there is an error")
});
```

Altough, still have not figured out how to make a dynamic query, to get a response, based on the url.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic query?